# How to split very long texts within a legend in Arcgis without converting them to graph or ungrouping them?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, legend

I have a very long layer name and I don't want it all to appear on a single line but rather to appear on two or three lines within the legend without having to convert the legend to a graphic and ungroup it.